# File input output read text file c++

Tags: c++

My task is to write a program that reads a text file, then prints some statistical results about its contents to an output file. Start by asking the user to input the name of the input file, and then to input the name of an output file. The input file can be any file containing plain text. So what I want it to do  is read the contents of the input file, and then print to the output file the following information about the contents of the input file. Also I am using MS Visual Studio for this assignment and I don't know if I am doing it right so far but I think I have to create a .cpp just for the input text file and one .cpp for the output file and then one for execution. I am kinda lost on creating and using the text files too. Here is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char filename[100];     // a string for filenames
    ifstream input;         // a file input stream
    ofstream output;        // a file output stream

    do
    {
        input.clear();      // to clear status flags in the stream
        cout << "Please enter the name of the input file.\n";
        cout << "Filename: ";
        cin >> filename;
        input.open(filename);
        if (!input)
            cout << "Sorry not a valid file. Try again!\n";
    } while (!input);



    do
    {
        output.clear();     // to clear status flags in the stream
        cout << "Please enter the name of the output file.\n";
        cout << "Filename: ";
        cin >> filename;
        output.open(filename);
        if (!output)
            cout << "Sorry not a valid file. Try again!\n";
    } while (!output);


    char ch;
    int characters = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int white_space = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int other_characters = 0;
    int uppercase = 0;
    int lowercase = 0;

    while (!input.eof());   // while not end of input file
    {
        input.get(ch);

        if(isalnum(ch))
            characters++;
        output << ch;

        if(isalpha(ch))
            ++letters;
        output << ch;

        if(isspace(ch))
            ++white_space;
        output << ch;

        if(isdigit(ch))
            ++digits;
        output << ch;

        if(ispunct(ch))
            ++other_characters;
        output << ch;

    }
    cout << "Processing complete\n";

    double perc_letters = 0;
    double perc_white_space = 0;
    double perc_digits = 0;
    double perc_other_characters = 0;

    cout << "\nStatistics for file:" << filename << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";

    cout << "Total # of charcters in file:\t " << characters << endl;
    cout << "\nCategory\tHow many in file\t% of file\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Letters\t" << letters << "\t" << perc_letters << "%" << endl;
    cout << "White space\t" << white_space << "\t" << perc_white_space << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Digits\t" << digits << "\t" << perc_digits << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Other characters\t" << other_characters << "\t" << perc_other_characters << "%" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    input.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what IS your question? "I don't know if I'm doing it right" is not a question. Neither is "I am kinda lost". If you have a specific question, ask it.

Comment: I just need to know how to get the text file...how to create one with something in it to test my program I have written. @Milen

Comment: You're already "getting" the file contents by opening it - input.open(filename); and then looping through it via input.getch.  Just create a blank text file in the same folder as the CPP file, add some random text to it, build and run the application in Visual Studio or whatever IDE you're using, then enter the file name. The code seems fine.

Comment: Ok so I create the text file in MS Visual studio where my code is. I was trying to create it on my computer path C: . I didn't kno you could create that file in MS Visual Studio @Milen

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make a difference if you put them in different cpp files, thats just for making a good structure of the code.
I am not 100% sure on how you are going to do your assignment but if you are using C++ then the getLine() function is really handy. You can do something like:

```
    while (std::getline(File, line)){
        if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' '){
            sscanf_s(&line[0], "v %f, &x);}
Thats gonna store a float value in x on that line if the line starts with: "v "
```